# How can I calculate int(exp(sin(x)),x) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

There's a warning when I tried to do an integration with MATLAB!

```
syms z
int(exp(sin(z)),z)
```

> Warning: Explicit integral could not be found.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha agrees: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral+e%5Esin%5Bx%5D+dx

Comment: Are you confused by the message "Explicit integral could not be found."?

Answer (score 4):

The expression `exp(sin(x))` does not have a known analytical formula for it's indefinite integral. Mathematica agrees with Matlab on this: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral+e%5Esin%5Bx%5D+dx.

While you can't evaluate the indefinite integral, you can compute definite integrals numerically to an arbitrary precision.